# Scraping data in dynamic sites

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from our local government. What I want is address from kids adoption offices. Here, in Brazil, all adoptions go through the government. So I have the URL of one office, there are 2 or 3 thousands more. But if I can manage to get one, the others will be easy.
I made many attempts, bellow I show three.

The problem could be related to a Javascript (Ajax maybe) that refresh the page.

Note: I am not a PHP developer.

First attempt

```
echo '<html><head></head><body>'; 
echo '<h1>Scraper PHP GET 1</h1>'; 

echo ini_get("allow_url_fopen");
echo ini_get("allow_url_fopen");

// I used this url for test
//$url = 'http://www.portaldaadocao.com.br'; 

//This is the URL that I really want
$url = 'http://www.cnj.jus.br/cna/Controle/ConsultaPublicaBuscaControle.php?transacao=CONSULTA&vara=2673';

$html = file_get_contents($url); 
var_dump($html); 

echo '</body></html>'; 

// Output
// 11
// Warning: 
file_get_contents(http://www.cnj.jus.br/cna/Controle/ConsultaPublicaBuscaControle.php?
transacao=CONSULTA&vara=2673) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP 
request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/rsl/www/sc01_get.php on line 14
// bool(false)
```

Second attempt

```
echo '<html><head></head><body>'; 
echo '<h1>Scraper PHP CURL 3</h1>'; 

// I used this url for test
//$url = 'http://www.portaldaadocao.com.br'; 

//This is the URL that I really want
$url = 'http://www.cnj.jus.br/cna/Controle/ConsultaPublicaBuscaControle.php?transacao=CONSULTA&vara=2673';

$curl = curl_init($url);
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "foo");
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");;

$html=@curl_exec($curl);

if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($curl);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}
else{
   echo '<br>begin HTML[';
    echo  $html;
   echo '<br>]end html '; 
}
echo '</body></html>'; 

// Output
// 1
```

third attempt

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.windowsphone.com");

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

echo '<html><head></head><body>'; 
echo '<h1>Scraper PHP CURL 5</h1>'; 

// I used this url for test
//$url = 'http://www.portaldaadocao.com.br'; 

//This is the URL that I really want
$url = 'http://www.cnj.jus.br/cna/Controle/ConsultaPublicaBuscaControle.php?transacao=CONSULTA&vara=2673';

$curl = curl_init($url);
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "foo");
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");;

$html=@curl($curl);


if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($curl);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}
else{
    echo '<br>begin HTML[';
    echo  $html;
    echo '<br>]end html '; 
}
echo '</body></html>'; 

// Output
// cURL error number:0
// cURL error:
```

Comment: If the pages are really ajax based meaning the information that you need to scrape is loaded or shown through javascript execution, you will need another approach. You would need to automate with a real browser. You can go the [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) route which can be written in a number of languages or use [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) with Javascript as the programming language.

Comment: I am studying Selenium right now. Interesting. So far I am able to recover one page.  Selenium have no problem with java refresh. GREAT. Now I need to understand how to save the page. 
Thanks.